# wordpress integer date to date

Tags: wordpress, type-conversion, sql-server-2016

I have a wordpress sql database that records CREATE_DATE in an integer format

some examples are

```
1615776024
1615852620
1616024968
1616027330
1616981834
```

some of the entries were created this month, so the format in which the date is recorded doesn't reveal anything about itself.

I have tried these but all of these statements error

```
SELECT

CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(CHAR(8),CREATE_DATE),112)
,CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CREATE_DATE))
,CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CREATE_DATE))

FROM WORDPRESS_TABLE
```

But they all error with the same error message :

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting
> date and/or time from character string.

can any one tell me how I can convert this into the following format please? dd/MM/yyyy in SQL?

Comment: what are those number represent ?

Comment: dates or datetime I presume, given the column name.. it's a remote mysql database and the metadata say integer for any date columns

Comment: You have to tell us those numbers represent what date ?

Comment: Is the database MySQL? What inserts the date data into the column? You say the integer represents date - is it date, or datetime?

Comment: It's a standard WordPress front end website that's inserts this data into a Mysql database.  I'm importing this data into  Sqlserver database and want to manipulate this "date" column. But there is no hint as to what the integer actually represents.. hence the question here.

Comment: @Harry, I assume you can't get to the code that inserts the data into the db? If you can do that, have a look and see what the code is doing. It seems that the data in the column  is based on a start-date, and shows number of days since start. If you can, try and ingest something through the frontend and see what the value of the data inserted is, and from there try to work backwards to what the data represents.

Comment: Thank you.. absolutely no chance for me to look at the front end code. Perhaps the next time a transaction happens.. I can record the datetime and then compare that to what is being recorded and work backwards as you hae suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having thought about it a bit more, (like 10 seconds); I wonder if what you see is not `epoch`. I.e. number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970. In that case you can quite easily convert it back to a proper date by: `SELECT DATEADD(S, [your-value], '1970-01-01')`.

Testing that on your first value in the original question: `SELECT DATEADD(S, 1615776024, '1970-01-01')`, gives me: `2021-03-15 02:40:24.000`.

This should "square" up with what you said above regarding newly created entries this month.